# Using TeamCity to deploy SSRS 2008 R2 Reporting Projects

Tags: reporting-services, teamcity

We are looking to integrate our SSRS 2008 R2 projects into our automated build process.  Currently three times a week TeamCity builds and deploys our C# codebase.  We'd like to add the SSRS report projects to that.  The RDL files are currently in a Subversion source control repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Report Server Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152787.aspx) for this purpose. It has [CreateItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.createcatalogitem.aspx) method that uploads report to Reporting Service.

To created C# project that uploads rdl files you will need to create [proxy class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155134.aspx) for your ReportService2010.asmx endpoint and then use is it like this:

```cs
ReportingService2010 reportingService = new ReportingService2010();
reportingService.Url = url + "/ReportService2010.asmx";
reportingService.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);
Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.Warning[] warnings = null;            

using (FileStream reportStream = new FileStream("c:\\report.rdl", 
       FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        reportStream.CopyTo(ms);
        CatalogItem report = reportingService.CreateCatalogItem(
            "Report",
            "Report1",
            "/",
            true,
            ms.ToArray(),
            null,
            out warnings);
     }
}
```